# problem in removing menu from layer

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I have added a menu when `touchesMove` fonction is been called as:

```
CCMenuItemImage * resetPosition =[CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"position.png" selectedImage: @"position_over.png"                              target:self
selector:@selector(reset:)]; 
resetPosition.position =ccp(400, 300);
myresetMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:resetPosition, nil];
myresetMenu.position = ccp(0,0);
[[self parent] addChild:myresetMenu z:10];
menuWithItems:resetPosition, nil];
```

And then in `reset` method i have removed this menu as:

```
- (void) reset: (CCMenuItem  *) menuItem 
{   
[self unschedule:@selector(reset:)];
[[self parent] removeChild:myresetMenu cleanup:YES];
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"btn_click.mp3"];
[self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-self.parent.position.x/650) position:ccp(0,0)]];
}
```

but `myresetMenu` is nor been removed. please assist me with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is not exactly  the answer of my question, but i have achieved the solution in given way.

Well I have implemented it by the following way:

```
if(diffX > 0)
{
[resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:round(-(-3112-self.parent.position.x)/650) 
                                                                 position:ccp((3112+self.position.x+400),resetPosition.position.y)]];
}
else
{
[resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:(-self.parent.position.x/650) 
                                                                 position:ccp(400,resetPosition.position.y)]];
}

- (void) reset
{   
CCLOG(@"reset Method Called");

[self.parent stopAllActions];
[resetPosition setIsEnabled:NO];
[resetPosition stopAllActions];

[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] playEffect:@"btn_click.mp3"];
[resetPosition runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.09f 
                                             position:ccp(400,300)]];   
[self.parent runAction:[CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:.09f position:ccp(0,0)]];
}
```

And in case of disable a transparent small button is been used.

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this is the answer but ur adding myrestmenu to parent twice and reset is only removing it once.

Comment: that was just copy mistake. :)

Comment: ah k :P where are u creating the menu? is it in a cclayer? why not just add it to the layer rather then its parent if thats the case? just [self addchild: menu z :10] and [self removechild: menu cleanup: yes]. also why are you passing a menu item in reset: and dont appear to be using it? and what is [self unschedule:@selector(reset:)]; for? not quite sure of the use in this case. sorry for the questions just trying to follow the problem .

Answer (score 1):

Add **CCMenu** as a variable to the class that owns it instead of creating it. Then you can add or remove it whenever you like. So in your interface file do something like:

```
@interface myLayerClass : CCLayer {
CCMenu *myMenu;
}
```

Comment: I already have did this: here myresetMenu is CCMenu, I have defined in my .h file